# not able to do ruby string comparision

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to do ruby string comparision which doesnt seem to work

```
max == "value"
if user.name == max
```

I also tried using the eql method but nothing seems to work

```
 max.eql(user.name)
```

This is not working althought the values are same.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of white spaces. Try doing

```
if user.name.strip == max
```

strip will remove all the white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Ruby use the same semantics as C when it comes to assignment versus comparison.

```
x = y
```

will assign `x` the value of `y` *Even if this is done inside an `if` expression*.

The second attempt to use `eql` (which really should be `eql?`) will fail, as `x.eql?(y)` returns `true` if the `x` and `y` are the *same* object. It is not sufficient that they have the same value.

Note, that in a language like Ruby, many variables can be bound to the same object. If you update the object destructively, this will be reflected on all variables bound to the same object. On the other hand, it will not affect variables bound the another object, even if that object happened to have an equal value as the first object.

*Update*: The poster changed the question after this answer was posted.